# Why is { : i ∈ I} a set according to Tao's replacement axiom? Terrence Tao Analysis 1 page 60

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

*Replacement axiom. Let  be a set. For any object ∈, and any object , suppose we have a statement (,) pertaining to  and , such that for each ∈ there is at most one  for which (,) is true. Then there exists a set {: (,) is true for some ∈}, such that for any object ,  ∈{: (,) is true for some ∈} ⇔ (,) is true for some ∈.*

Using this axiom why is the set { : i ∈ I} a set? I am not sure how to use Tao's axiom of replacement to argue that this is indeed a set, would it be stated as something like:

let I be a set and let P(i, Y) be the statement that for each i ∈ I let Y =  where  is a set?

But in order to use this axiom we need there to be **at most one**  for each i ∈ I.

couldnt each i ∈ I also get mapped to another set say Z, so the axiom would fail to imply the above is a set?

i am confused!

Comment: The notation implies that there is a unique $X_i$ for each $i\in I$.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the statement $P(x, y)$ is to associate members of $A$, labeled $x$, with members of $Y$, labeled $y$.

So for the set $\{X_i : i \in I\}$, our "source" set is $I$, whose elements are labeled as $i$, while our "destination" set is $Y$, whose elements are $X_i$ (which don't have to be sets). That means that our statement would be $P(i, X_i)$, since that pairs the elements of $I$ with the corresponding elements of $Y$.

The replacement axiom asks only that our statement has at most one $y$ for each $x$ - or in our case, at most one $X_i$ for each $i$. For example, if my set $I$ were the numbers $1, 2, 3, 4$, then my statement $P(i, X_i)$:

1. Can only be true for each value of $i$ once - I can't have $P(1, A)$ and $P(1, B)$ where $A \neq B$. (This is one side of the "at most one" part.)
2. Can skip values of $i$ - I don't *have* to have any statements of the form $P(3, C)$. (This is the other side of the "at most one" part.)
3. Can repeat values of $X_i$ for different values of $i$ - I can have $P(2, D)$ and $P(4, D)$. (This comes from the fact that there is actually no restriction on how often $y$ appears in the axiom.)

Also importantly, the Replacement axiom just asks that such a statement *exists*. It doesn't require that the statement be *unique*. So when you ask "couldn't each $i$ get mapped to another set" then the answer is "not using the same statement". The point of the axiom is that you meet the conditions however you like, and the conclusion is then considered a foregone result. If you have a statement $P$ that doesn't satisfy the whole "at most one $y$ for each $x$" part, you can't apply the axiom. If you have two statements, $P$ and $P'$ that both satisfy the conditions, then you can pick either one for the axiom, and this is essentially re-indexing the set.

Comment: Well, one way to look at it is that if we have a statement P then we can construct a set Y based on it - that's why it's called the Replacement Axiom, because we're taking the values x from the original set A and replacing them with new values y. In this case, we're constructing Y using A and P as the foundation.

The other way to look at it (which is more useful for the construction we're looking at here) is that if we have a "thing" Y that contains a bunch of values Xi, then as long as we can find a statement P that maps values from some other set onto the Xi then we can also call Y a set.

Comment: Ah right but what i am asking is why is it true that for each i in  there is a unique ? Is this simply because we are constructing it this way (as we are allowed to do) so we can apply replacement. What im trying to say is are we constructing our statement like this: Let P(i, ) be the statement that each i in  there is a corresponding unique set denoted . Sorry for multiple questions, this has been bugging me for days.

Comment: like ok we found our statement P(i , ) that links each i to  that’s one part, now we need to show the second part is satisfied namely each i in   has at most one .

Comment: $X_i$ is, by nature, a single item, so $P(i, X_i)$ is by construction a unique statement. If you wanted to get fancy, then you can say that with the statements $P(i, X_i)$ and $P(j, X_j)$, if $i = j$ then it immediately follows that $X_i = X_j$ and hence there is only one $X_i$ for each $i$.